# Same z-index does not yield wanted box-shadow effect

Tags: css, box-shadow

[box shadow codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Byeomx)

```
#b {
  background: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

#c {
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

I am trying to get elements with the same z-level to not overlap each other in their box shadows.  In the linked example, everything has a z-level of 2 but the box shadow of the middle element is overlapping the upper element.  I would have thought that this wouldn't happen given that the two elements are on the same plane.  Any suggestions?

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/85ee6td6/

Comment: The fact that they have the same z-index doesn't change the fact that #c is drawn after #b, because it occurs later in the code. If you don't want a shadow to occur somewhere, don't put a shadow there.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the **order the elements being drawn matters** in case the z-index differs.

To me, the solution was to put all shadow-casting elements into a container which casts the shadow of the contained elements instead.

```css
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
  <p>shadow-casting element 1</p>
  <p>shadow-casting element 2</p>
</div>
<p>normal element</p>
```